# How it enable check-in /check out in OneDrive business

Tags: onedrive-for-business

I would like to enable check-in and checkout for onedrive
Is this possible and if yes how?
Thanks is in advance

Comment: What would be the purpose for doing so? ODfB is designed for personal storage, not to be shared among a larger group of individuals, so the need for check in/out doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm glad I found this page to clarify that it's not just me running into these limitations. And, of course, this post is YEARS old. And I'm running into what you ran into. Ugh.

Answer (score 4):

With SharePoint and OneDrive for business, if you Sync a document library from a site, AND enable Check-in/Check-out on that document library - When you try open the file from your PC in the OneDrive for Business folder - the item will open as read-only.

You cannot check-out the file from opening it from OneDrive for Business. However, if you want to use check-in/check-out, you need to **open** the file from the Browser (Firefox, ie, etc.) and either use the Excel/Word app in the browser to activate the Check-Out, OR **open** the file from the Browser and click Edit in Desktop version of Word Excel.

It is highly frustrating that you cannot use check-in/check-out with OneDrive for business app on your PC.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you not perform a checkIn/checkOut from the OneDrive for Business explorer extension, if you SYNC the drive from SharePoint to your machine, then open it from the browser it will no longer be editable because Excel/Word will find that mapping from Sharepoint to your local disk and will mark the file as read-only - and you won't be able to check it out or save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

....And if you have files like autocadfiles that is not supported with a Web viewer stored on your sharepoint, you can't edit them at all. Really frustrating... And i know that the Check In/Check out function used to be supported in file explorer for synchronized sharepoint files....